# hello world. this is my stopwatch class. return the value in seconds

Tags: java, stopwatch

this is my stopwatch class. my question is that how can i convert it to seconds so that it gives me the output in seconds? thanks in advance

```
public class StopWatch

{  
   /**
      Constructs a stopwatch that is in the stopped state
      and has no time accumulated.
   */
   public StopWatch()

   {  

 reset();

   }

   /**
      Starts the stopwatch. Time starts accumulating now.
   */
   public void start()

   {  

      if (isRunning) return;

      isRunning = true;

      startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

   }

   /**
      Stops the stopwatch. Time stops accumulating and is
      is added to the elapsed time.
   */
   public void stop()

   {  

      if (!isRunning) return;

      isRunning = false;

      long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

      elapsedTime = elapsedTime + endTime - startTime;

   }

   /**
      Returns the total elapsed time.
      @return the total elapsed time
   */
   public long getElapsedTime()

   {  

      if (isRunning) 

      {  

         long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

         return elapsedTime + endTime - startTime;

      }

      else

         return elapsedTime;

   }

   /**
      Stops the watch and resets the elapsed time to 0.
   */
   public void reset()

   {  

      elapsedTime = 0;

      isRunning = false;

   }

   private long elapsedTime;

   private long startTime;

   private boolean isRunning;

}
```

Comment: Excuse me, are you asking how to convert milliseconds into seconds ?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert time units with [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum. Just use [convert](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method like

```
//lets see how many seconds are in 1234 milliseconds 
System.out.println(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(1234, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
//output: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Guava libraries [com.google.common.base.Stopwatch](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) class, no need to reinvent the wheel.